# Check if two 1-D arrays are equal

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

This is the code I've tried:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])

if a[0] == [1, 2, 3]:
    print("equal")
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `np.all()`, as the error message tells you. Doing `==` on a numpy array will return an that's the same shape as the original array, only with True and False values in. They'll be True if the items at the particular index are equal, and False otherwise. `.all()` will only return `True` if *every* item in the array is True, so it will return True if the arrays are perfectly equal:

```
if np.all(a[0] == [1, 2, 3]):
    print("equal")
```

Output:

```
equal
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [`numpy.array_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html):

```py
In [32]: if np.array_equal(a[0], [1, 2, 3]):
    ...:     print("equal")
equal
```